# WebView containing Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, cocoa, webkit, webview

In my cocoa application I have a WebView.  If I set that WebView to display a web page that contains Silverlight, the mouse move event never fires in that Silverlight application (with the exception of if I hold down the mouse button while moving).  Everything else seems to work fine (clicking, interacting with objects) except for mouse move.  Anyone have any ideas what is causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the problem was.  When Silverlight is embedded in a WebView (from WebKit) appears to have different concerns regarding threading (Firefox on OS X does not exhibit this problem).  The solution was making sure that anything that touched a UI Object was in a control.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke (specifically in my case I was changing the text on a TextBlock in response to a MouseMove and that was causing the whole MouseMove to error out).

Hope this helps someone.